# Разные лейауты для разных телефонов

Tags: android, android-layout

Такая проблема. Создаем приложение для зоопарка устройств. и необходимо чтобы дизайн совпадал пиксель в пиксель. Впринципе все смогли разрулить с помощью dpi, выставляя значения в них. на разных екранах делаем скрин, вставляем в фотошоп и все накладывается пиксель в пиксель. Но есть такие телефоны типо нексуса 6, у которых нет конкретного размера в  dpi тоесть он между xxhdpi  и  xxxhdpi. И соотвественно когда я указываю размер кнопки например 50dpi то она выглядит иначе чем я ожидаю. Я не знаю как это решить. Из этого вопросы

1. Как это решается?
2. Как сделать чтобы на определенном телефоне поставлялся определенный лейаут?

НАШЕЛ

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

смущает `600dp wide and bigger` это что этот лейаут будет и для экранов с большей плотностью тоже? а как сделать только для конкретного экрана?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: уже нашел эту статью изучаю

Comment: Вы понимаете разницу между плотностью пикселов(денсити) и размером экрана?

Comment: да я понимаю разницу. что вы предлагаете? задача очевидна. я хочу чтобы на всех экранах все было одинаково. для этого я все размеры задаю в DP. и они отображаются одинаково везде. Но есть устройства на которых эти же размеры отображаются не корректно. напрмер нексус 6. У него и у самсунга одинаковое разрешение. но разная плотность. почти одинаковые размеры экранов. но на нексусе все выглядит очень мелким. ка кэто исправить?

Comment: Ок, отлично. Способа задать размер конкретно под Nexus6, типа  drawable-560dp к сожалению нет, поэтому см. ответ Barmaley. Даже больше скажу - на рутованных девайсах можно менять зашитое значение денсити программно, чтобы делать шрифты крупнее или меньше. Это вообще ломает всю систему напрочь.

Comment: чтобы делать шрифты крупнее или меньше это еще хуже. наш дизайнер делает межбуквенные интервалы в шрифтах. ка кэто реализовать вообще жесть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно например так:

```
if(android.os.Build.MODEL.contains("Nexus 6"))
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_for_nexus_6);
```

Мне и самому то не нравится такое выделывать, но что делать раз Nexus такой специфичный :)

Comment: Да, 6  и 9 нексусы еще та свинья разработчикам, как и 7 первого поколения - первый с промежуточной денсити, второй нестандартными пропорциями

Comment: у меня так же есть LG g3 mini( с такой же полоской снизу - программные кнопки навигации). И куча девайсов не входящих в размеры  xxhdpi xxxhdpi xhdpi и тд, а находящиеся между ними. и как быть? писать кучу ифов?))) я подумал что оптимальней делать для них сови лейауты. или может есть еще решения?

Comment: Ну как вариант ведь можно относительные размеры задавать через веса и относительное положение элементов и использовать 9.png конечно будет не пиксель в пискель, но вполне можно приемлемых результатов достичь.

Comment: А при чем тут куча девайсов не входящих в размеры xxhdpi xxxhdpi xhdpi и на что она влияет? (вообще мне известен только один такой девайс - nexus 6, может еще китайфоны какие-то)

Comment: смотри. у меня в фотошопе макет. 1440х 2560 пикселей. это  xxxhdpi и такое же разрешение у самсунга гелекси ноута 4 и и у нексуса. но плотность у них разная. и у нексуса полоска снизу. так вот в макете кнопка 100 пикселей шириной. значит я высчитываю это в калькуляторе в xxxhdpi - 25.00dp. теперь когда я запускаю на устройстве с любой плотностью все выводиться одинаково. Но на нексусе разрешение такое же но плотность меньше. и кнопка в  25.00dp вглядит совсем не так как надо

Comment: хоть и поздно, но скажу так, если тестируете на эмуляторах смотрите:  adb -s [DEVICE] shell dumpsys display , так как могут возвращаться не "родные" density , я сам столкнулся, правда я разрешение ставил меньше, так как не думал. что это влияет, оказывается влияет.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus 6 - 730 x 410 dp
Nexus 9 - 1024 x 768 dp

Если используются разные layout'ы для портретной и альбомной ориентации (как часто бывает), то можно учесть это:

> In order to take advantage of the screen real estate on the Nexus 6
>   and Nexus 9, we emphasize the importance of responsive design. In the
>   past, if you assumed that landscape mode is significantly wider than
>   portrait mode, you may run into problems on a device like the Nexus 9,
>   which has an aspect ratio of 4:3. Instead of declaring layouts using
>   the layout-land or layout-port resource folder qualifiers, we strongly
>   recommend switching to the `w<N>dp` width resource folder qualifier so
>   that content is laid out based on available screen width.

Тогда для Nexus 6 получаем `layout-w410dp-h730dp` (портретная) и `layout-w730dp-h410dp` (альбомная)

Comment: у Nexus 6 размер экрана 730 x 410 dp - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Comment: @anber оттуда же: It has a quantized density of 560 dpi

Comment: Вы путаете размер с денсити. Тут или `layout-sw410dp` или `drawable-xxxhdpi`

Comment: это вариант. создать свой лейаут для нексуса. а можно свои деменшины создать для определенного телефона?

Comment: не работает этот вариант

Comment: @IP696 исправил ответ с учетом замечания от anber

Comment: не пашит. я так делал уже. и еще раз. не пашит. только если layout-xxxhdpi  папкуи в нее положит то хавает. но тогда и мой зенфон xhdpi тоже этот лейаут ест. все достало.

Answer (score 1):

Кроме всего ранее озвученного можно попробовать вынести размеры елементов и шрифтов в dimens. Причем раскидать их по папкам с комбинацией денсити и размера:

```
values-sw320dp-xhdpi
values-sw600dp-xhdpi
values-sw720dp-xhdpi
values-sw320dp-xxhdpi
values-sw600dp-xxhdpi
values-sw720dp-xxhdpi
values-sw320dp-xxxhdpi
values-sw600dp-xxxhdpi
values-sw720dp-xxxhdpi
```

см. также http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html